# Hint the compiler that float-vector count is divisible by 8?

Tags: c++, vectorization, compiler-optimization

```
static inline void R1_sub_R0(float *vec,  size_t cnt,  float toSubtract){
    for(size_t i=0; cnt; ++i){
        vec[i] -= toSubtract;
    }
}
```

I know that `cnt` will always be divisible by 8, therefore the code could be vectorized via SSE and AVX. In other words, we can iterate over `*vec` as a `__m256` type.
But compiler will probably not know this. **How to re-assure the compiler that this count is guaranteed to be divisible by 8?**

Will something like this help it? (if we stick it at the start of the function)

```
assert(((cnt*sizeof(float)) % sizeof(__m256)) ==0 );  //checks that it's "multiple of __m256 type".
```

Of course, I could have simply written the whole thing as a vectorized code:

```
static inline void R1_sub_R0(float *vec,  size_t cnt,  float toSubtract){
    assert(cnt*sizeof(float) % sizeof(__m256) == 0);//check that it's "multiple of __m256 type".
    assert(((uintptr_t)(const void *)(POINTER)) % (16) == 0);//assert that 'vec' is 16-byte aligned

    __m256 sToSubtract = _mm256_set1_ps(toSubtract);
    __m256 *sPtr = (__m256*)vec;
    const __m256 *sEnd = (const __m256*)(vec+cnt);

    for(sPtr;  sPtr != sEnd;  ++sPtr){
        *sPtr = _mm256_sub_ps(*sPtr, sToSubtract);
    }
}
```

However, it runs 10% slower than the original version.
So I just want to give the compiler extra bit of information. That way it could vectorize the code even more efficiently.

Comment: Do you have to take a pointer?  If you can take an array then the compiler can know the size and optimize appropriately. (or at least have a decent chance at it)

Comment: The loop is infinite.

Comment: How large is your `cnt`? Note that if it is very large (much much larger than 8), the vast majority of array elements should be processed by SIMD instructions anyway. Look, e.g., at the assembly generated by GCC for AVX2 architecture: https://godbolt.org/z/7Ct0jn. You may observe that properly aligned elements are processed within the `.L4` loop, which is vectorized. Only the not aligned head and tail elements are processed without vectorization. If `cnt` is very large, there should be only negligible runtime difference.

Comment: I just looked at the assembly generated by GCC linked in my previous comment and realized that GCC is not so smart. It processes the majority of elements by SIMD instructions, however, does not care about their alignment, which generally will be slower. However, what I described actually does Intel compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/dJ_OVS. There is a "sequential" loop both before and after the vectorized loop, which process head and tail elements, respectively. It's kind of surprising that GCC is not able to perform the same optimization. Nevertheless, if your array is aligned, GCC is fine.

Comment: What if you pass `cnt` divided by 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Hint the compiler that float-vector count is divisible by 8?

You could semi-unroll the loop by nesting another:

```
for(size_t i=0; i < cnt; i += 8){
    for(size_t j=0; j < 8; j++){
        vec[i + j] -= toSubtract;
    }
}
```

The compiler can easily see that the inner loop has constant iterations and can unroll it and potentially use SIMD if it so chooses.

> Hint the compiler that float-vector count is [16-byte aligned]?

This is quite a bit more tricky.

You could use something like:

```
struct alignas(16) sse {
    float arr[8];
};

 // cnt is now number of structs which is 8th fraction of original cnt
R1_sub_R0(sse *vec,  size_t cnt,  float toSubtract) {
    for(size_t i=0; i < cnt; i ++){
        for(size_t j=0; j < 8; j++){
            vec[i].arr[j] -= toSubtract;
        }
    }
```

Other than that, there are compiler extensions such as `__builtin_assume_aligned` that can be used with the plain float array.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized we also have to reassure the compiler that `vec` is 16-byte aligned. Would it be important? Otherwise it still might not use SIMD, even with the semi-unrolling.

Comment: @Kari Good point; that would typically be necessary for SIMD.

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to microoptimize here, the compiler will generate the fastest code if you just communicate to it what you want to be done, not how you want it to be done. Therefore i would use std::transform.

```
std::transform(vec, vec + cnt, vec, 
[toSubstract](float f){return f - toSubstract;});
```